# You do not have the required role to enable Auto Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am seeing this alert when trying to create a table. I've added the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess policy to my IAM user as per [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.Console.html).

I've signed out/in, but still get this message. Is there an additional policy I need to enable autoscaling in DynamoDB?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:*",
                "dax:*",
                "application-autoscaling:DeleteScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:DeregisterScalableTarget",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalableTargets",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
                "application-autoscaling:DescribeScalingPolicies",
                "application-autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
                "application-autoscaling:RegisterScalableTarget",
                "cloudwatch:DeleteAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmHistory",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
                "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarmsForMetric",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricAlarm",
                "datapipeline:ActivatePipeline",
                "datapipeline:CreatePipeline",
                "datapipeline:DeletePipeline",
                "datapipeline:DescribeObjects",
                "datapipeline:DescribePipelines",
                "datapipeline:GetPipelineDefinition",
                "datapipeline:ListPipelines",
                "datapipeline:PutPipelineDefinition",
                "datapipeline:QueryObjects",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "sns:CreateTopic",
                "sns:DeleteTopic",
                "sns:ListSubscriptions",
                "sns:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "sns:ListTopics",
                "sns:Subscribe",
                "sns:Unsubscribe",
                "sns:SetTopicAttributes",
                "lambda:CreateFunction",
                "lambda:ListFunctions",
                "lambda:ListEventSourceMappings",
                "lambda:CreateEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:DeleteEventSourceMapping",
                "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration",
                "lambda:DeleteFunction"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                        "dax.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                        "replication.dynamodb.amazonaws.com",
                        "dax.amazonaws.com",
                        "dynamodb.application-autoscaling.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't know if you've already found an answer to this, but what you have to do is to go in on "Roles" in "IAM" and create a new role. You choose "Application Auto Scaling" and then "Application Auto Scaling -DynamoDB" click next a few more times and you're done. It doesn't appear that the current documentation covers this step.

Comment: I did these steps and it failed saying I already have the role.  So someone on my team already did these steps.  However, I still lack permissions when I use the AWS CLI.  Am I missing a step of associating the role with a user?  Am I misunderstanding how roles should be used?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it needs a **Service-linked role** to give permissions that allow DynamoDB to modify tables (as opposed to *your* permissions).

See:

- [Using the AWS CLI to Manage DynamoDB Auto Scaling - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.CLI.html)
- [Using the AWS Management Console With DynamoDB Auto Scaling - Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.Console.html)
- [Service-Linked Roles for Application Auto Scaling - Application Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-autoscaling-service-linked-roles.html)
- [AWS DynamoDB – A NoSQL Database Service – Site Title](https://xiongyeblog.wordpress.com/2017/10/15/aws-dynamodb-a-nosql-database-service/)

Comment: The instructions do indicate the need for the service-linked role AWSServiceRoleForApplicationAutoScaling_DynamoDBTable. It then states that the role will be automatically created. From your third link: "You don't need to manually create the service-linked roles for Application Auto Scaling. Application Auto Scaling creates the appropriate service-linked role for you when you call RegisterScalableTarget or PutScalingPolicy." Are there other manual steps I am missing?